# plotting multiple series on a single plot

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

I am learning python while working overtime and using google for help. I stuck at a point where I couldn't google it correctly so came here to ask for help. Thanks for reading so far.

I have a dataframe  with many columns. I need to make a plot between two columns. Say, between Column-1 and Column-3. The range of column-3 needs to be based on a constant value in column-2. So as soon as value in Column-2 changes I need to make a new column-1 vs column-3 plot. Also, I want all series plots on a single plot(figure). Thanks. My data looks like this below.

[I have shown the data I have as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G8za.png)

The code I am using is given below (It is working but creating several plots but I want all series on same plot):

```
    temp=df['Column-2'].unique().tolist()
    print(temp)
    for i in temp:
        dfx=df[df['Column-2']==i]
        plt.plot(dfx["Column-1"], dfx["Column-3"])
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @sheldore should i change the wording? Thanks.

Comment: You want to modify your dataframe inside the loop. But, keep the plotting outside it.

Comment: @Sameeresque thaks for comment. I need to think about it. Cheers